# Why does this function that finds the sum of a series in Sigma notation keep going wrong?

Tags: javascript

```
var sigmaAnswer = 0
var sigmaFinder = function(start,finish,arguement){
    for(var i = start; i<=finish;i++ ){
        sigmaAnswer += arguement
    }
    console.log(sigmaAnswer)
}
```

Disclaimer: I am a fairly new to JS, so try to keep things in simple terms.

EDIT: I changed =+ to +=
EDIT 2: "var" removed from inside the function.

Comment: I think you mean `+=` rather than `=+`.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? What's your input, output and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's got a few problems; some minor, others less so.

First of all, you declare `var sigmaAnswer` at the outer scope. Presumably, you want to modify that variable from within `sigmaFinder`. However, you declare a *new* variable called `sigmaAnswer` inside `sigmaFinder` that *hides* the one from the outer scope. If you wish to refer to the variable from the outer scope, you'll need to remove the `var` from the inner `sigmaAnswer`.

Secondly, `sigmaAnswer =+ arguement` probably doesn't do what you want. Put another way, you wrote `sigmaAnswer = (+arguement)`. For a number `x`, `+x` just returns `x`, so you've got approximately `sigmaAnswer = arguement`. You probably meant `+=`, which is equivalent to `sigmaAnswer = sigmaAnswer + arguement`.

Lastly, I'm going to assume you're calling it like this:

```
sigmaFinder(0, 10, i);
```

If so, I believe your intent is for the third argument to be an expression with `i` unbound and only bound once you add it to `sigmaAnswer`. Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't work like that. It'll try to find the value of `i` right then and there, and at that time, there's no `i` in scope, and it will fail with a `ReferenceError`.

The answer to this is trickier than the others. Rather than passing a bare expression like that which won't work, we'll need to create a function and pass that in. For example:

```
function f(i) {
    return i
}
sigmaFinder(0, 10, f)
```

Then, in `sigmaFinder`, we can't just use `arguement`, but we have to use `arguement(i)` to explicitly call that function. Fortunately, there's a more concise way than writing a named function and passing it in: you can use an anonymous function:

```
sigmaFinder(0, 10, function(i) { return i })
```

I think that's all of your problems, but lastly I should note you've got a minor spelling error, though it won't actually break anything: `arguement` should be spelled `argument`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said exactly how your code is going wrong, but I'll take a guess that the problem is with the way you're declaring and initializing sigmaAnswer outside the function, when you probably want to do that inside the function.

Second, I'm guessing that "sigma" is supposed to be a summing function, but the function you've written is not actually making a sum. What you'e written is this:

```
    var sigmaAnswer =+ arguement
```

when you maybe really want this (notice the transposed + and = signs):

```
    sigmaAnswer += arguement
```

Both `=+` and `+=` are valid JavaScript, but they mean very different things.

Also, the `var` declaration and initialization should come before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an example to what icktoofay recommended

http://jsfiddle.net/DPMmS/

```
var sigmaAnswer = 0;
var sigmaExpression = function (i){ return i;};
var sigmaFinder = function(start,finish,arguement){
for(var i = start; i<=finish;i++ ){
     sigmaAnswer += arguement(i);
}
alert(sigmaAnswer);
};

sigmaFinder(1, 12, sigmaExpression);
```

Comment: But what does arguement(i) do? There was never a function made called arguement, it is just the parameter.

Comment: how you intend to call sigmaFinder?

Comment: If you don't pass a function argument, the summation function will work only for one fixed expression like, for {i=s to n}sum(i), and when we want summation of i^2, we would have to change our summation function. A simple way of creating summation function for one fixed expression would be like this [link]http://jsfiddle.net/DPMmS/2/